# Psexec to execute batch file,which calls a vbscript,and this vbscript executes test case using qtp on a remote machine

Tags: file, batch-file, vbscript, qtp, psexec

Scenario :

System 1(Remote Machine) :

1. "abc.bat"
2. "xyz.vbs"

Both the files are in D Drive

Scenario : "abc.bat" calls "xyz.vbs" and the command is like this: cscript D:\xyz.vbs
           "xyz.vbs has script which calls QTP and executes the test script on QTP.

System 2(My Machine) :

I have downloaded PSTools and making use of Psexec command to execute batch file on above remote machine.
In my cmd i have this command.

C:\Program Files\PSTools>psexec -i \System_1's_IP_address -u domain\username -p password D:\abc.bat

When i run this command on my machine, it starts PSexec on remote machine. But QTP is not invoked on the remote machine so execution halts here.

I have checked in task manager.it shows wscript,psexec.
But not QTPro.exe

Is there a solution??

Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
PSEXEC \\<Targetsystem> -u domain\username -p password -i -w D: cmd.exe /c abc.bat
```

or

place the abc.bat in the same folder as psexec and execute this one:

```
PSEXEC \\<Targetsystem> -u domain\username -p password -i -c -f abc.bat
```

(P.S.: a look at `PSEXEC /?` may help ;))